# C++ Help with Separating Axis Theorem

Tags: opengl, c++, collision-detection, mathematics, separating-axis-theorem

I am trying to detect collision between two triangles using Separating Axis Theorem however I am unaware what is wrong with my code. The CollisionHelper::isTriangleIntersectingTriangle is called every frame and passes in the vertices of both triangles. It never returns true, however. I've been stuck on this for days now. Any help is appreciated.

```
glm::vec3 CalcSurfaceNormal(glm::vec3 tri1, glm::vec3 tri2, glm::vec3 tri3)
{
    //Subtracts each coordinate respectively
    glm::vec3 u = tri2 - tri1;
    glm::vec3 v = tri3 - tri1;

    glm::vec3 nrmcross = glm::cross(u, v);
    nrmcross = glm::normalize(nrmcross);
    return nrmcross;
}

bool SATTriangleCheck(glm::vec3 axis, glm::vec3 tri1vert1, glm::vec3 tri1vert2, glm::vec3 tri1vert3, glm::vec3 tri2vert1, glm::vec3 tri2vert2, glm::vec3 tri2vert3)
{
    int t1v1 = glm::dot(axis, tri1vert1);
    int t1v2 = glm::dot(axis, tri1vert2);
    int t1v3 = glm::dot(axis, tri1vert3);
    int t2v1 = glm::dot(axis, tri2vert1);
    int t2v2 = glm::dot(axis, tri2vert2);
    int t2v3 = glm::dot(axis, tri2vert3);

    int t1min = glm::min(t1v1, glm::min(t1v2, t1v3));
    int t1max = glm::max(t1v1, glm::max(t1v2, t1v3));
    int t2min = glm::min(t2v1, glm::min(t2v2, t2v3));
    int t2max = glm::max(t2v1, glm::max(t2v2, t2v3));


    if ((t1min < t2max && t1min > t2min) || (t1max < t2max && t1max > t2min))
            return true;
    if ((t2min < t1max && t2min > t1min) || (t2max < t1max && t2max > t1min))
            return true;

    return false;
}

bool CollisionHelper::isTriangleIntersectingTriangle(glm::vec3 tri1, glm::vec3 tri2, glm::vec3 tri3, glm::vec3 otherTri1, glm::vec3 otherTri2, glm::vec3 otherTri3)
{
    //Triangle surface normals, 2 axes to test
    glm::vec3 tri1FaceNrml = CalcSurfaceNormal(tri1, tri2, tri3);
    glm::vec3 tri2FaceNrml = CalcSurfaceNormal(otherTri1, otherTri2, otherTri3);

    glm::vec3 tri1Edge1 = tri2 - tri1;
    glm::vec3 tri1Edge2 = tri3 - tri1;
    glm::vec3 tri1Edge3 = tri3 - tri2;
    glm::vec3 tri2Edge1 = otherTri2 - otherTri1;
    glm::vec3 tri2Edge2 = otherTri3 - otherTri1;
    glm::vec3 tri2Edge3 = otherTri3 - otherTri2;

    //axes
    //TODO: may need to (un)normalize the cross products
    glm::vec3 axis1 = tri1FaceNrml;
    glm::vec3 axis2 = tri2FaceNrml;
    glm::vec3 axis3 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(tri1Edge1, tri2Edge1));
    glm::vec3 axis4 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(tri1Edge1, tri2Edge2));
    glm::vec3 axis5 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(tri1Edge1, tri2Edge3));
    glm::vec3 axis6 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(tri1Edge2, tri2Edge1));
    glm::vec3 axis7 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(tri1Edge2, tri2Edge2));
    glm::vec3 axis8 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(tri1Edge2, tri2Edge3));
    glm::vec3 axis9 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(tri1Edge3, tri2Edge1));
    glm::vec3 axis10 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(tri1Edge3, tri2Edge2));
    glm::vec3 axis11 = glm::normalize(glm::cross(tri1Edge3, tri2Edge3));

    //Perform SAT
    if (SATTriangleCheck(axis1, tri1, tri2, tri3, otherTri1, otherTri2, otherTri3)) return true;
    if (SATTriangleCheck(axis2, tri1, tri2, tri3, otherTri1, otherTri2, otherTri3)) return true;
    if (SATTriangleCheck(axis3, tri1, tri2, tri3, otherTri1, otherTri2, otherTri3)) return true;
    if (SATTriangleCheck(axis4, tri1, tri2, tri3, otherTri1, otherTri2, otherTri3)) return true;
    if (SATTriangleCheck(axis5, tri1, tri2, tri3, otherTri1, otherTri2, otherTri3)) return true;
    if (SATTriangleCheck(axis6, tri1, tri2, tri3, otherTri1, otherTri2, otherTri3)) return true;
    if (SATTriangleCheck(axis7, tri1, tri2, tri3, otherTri1, otherTri2, otherTri3)) return true;
    if (SATTriangleCheck(axis8, tri1, tri2, tri3, otherTri1, otherTri2, otherTri3)) return true;
    if (SATTriangleCheck(axis9, tri1, tri2, tri3, otherTri1, otherTri2, otherTri3)) return true;
    if (SATTriangleCheck(axis10, tri1, tri2, tri3, otherTri1, otherTri2, otherTri3)) return true;
    if (SATTriangleCheck(axis11, tri1, tri2, tri3, otherTri1, otherTri2, otherTri3)) return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Separating axis theorem is a strange choice of collision detection algorithm to use when your inputs are two triangles in 3D. Usually we use it for 3D primitives like bounding boxes. For triangular primitives you can simply find the line of intersection of the triangles' planes, and check whether there's an interval along that line contained in both triangles.

Comment: How exactly would I go about doing/implementing that in C++?

Comment: Presumably you started by [searching for existing solutions/guides/Q&A](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=c%2B%2B+triangle+intersection&ia=qa)? What have you tried based on your research thus far?

Comment: I was reading a collision detection book. It said there are 3 methods of triangle to triangle intersection which it did not give any examples or explain implementation (Real time collision detection is the book, theres a triangle to triangle intersection section). From what I read, there are 3 methods. One I didn't understand. One was a paper on Moellers method which was way too advanced and I didn't understand it. The third option was separating axis theorem which I figured would be good to get working now since I'll use it for AABB, OBB, etc. Tried to implement SAT and now I'm here